# WLAN and DSL Speeds

Tags: wireless-networking, dsl

I'm having WLAN problems, and they are no doubt causing modem/router errors. Can reducing the speed of the signal improve the stability of the signal while my tech support determines the issue on the system?

Comment: Reducing the line speed may help in the short term. Without your line stats it's hard to tell. See [::. Kitz - Get DSL line stats .::](https://kitz.co.uk/adsl/frogstats.php) and [edit] the question with your line stats.

Comment: I’m not sure I follow. You may have *Wi-Fi* problems, but how would that *cause* router errors? What “signal” speed do you want to decrease? Or is it perhaps the exact opposite: You have DSL problems, which result in unreliable Internet connectivity?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, absolutely.  That is the idea of applying different profiles to the line.

To be clear this is normally simething the Telco does - I know in NZ tjis is readjysted automatically. Making changes using QoS or rate limiting on your router wont help - it needs to be programmed into yhe DSL negotiation.

If you are dar from the cabinet/exchange this us ok to fo. If its a new thing, the Telci should fix the underlying problem on the pair running to your location as it will likely get worse otherwise.